# How to use Navicat to connect to Postgresql socket via SSH?

Tags: postgresql, navicat

While the SSH tunnel functionality in Navicat seems to work well if postgresql is running on a TCP port, it seems impossible for me to make it work when postgresql is accessible using a file socket?!

Is this true, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Correct. There's no sensible way to connect to a unix socket over a ssh forward. You could possibly use `socat` to link a forwarded tcp/ip port to a unix socket, but I wouldn't bet on it working.

Just use TCP/IP.